# How to fix modeling geometry/topology error after applying all modifiers?

Tags: modeling, topology

So I have been working on modeling a simple character, and used mirror modifier to mirror my object, but due to some problems happened while modeling, When I applied my modifiers, the part had the problem looks as if my character had a bad stomach surgery

[image]

The whole body was very regular and looking very good, but that part looked like really bad thing happend, so my question is how to re-regularize that part again? I don't care that shape of the stomach might differ, I could remodel it or sculpt it, but my goal is to regain those regular squares modeling that part again. I thought of removing all faces that are deformed and form a new big face making loop cuts, but things got very very missy.

Can anyone suggest how to solve such a problem?

I have added my blend file here, in case you would like to inspect the model much more

[image]

Comment: You should have much less edge loops, did you apply a Subdivision Surface modifier? You should not, use this modifier to smooth your object but don't apply unless you have good reason to (and always keep a non-applied version)

Comment: maybe...if you are lucky, there is an xxxxxx_autosave.blend file in your folder with a few minutes before...then just load that and do again the things, you did from then.

Answer (score 0):

Enter edit mode, select the whole mesh, in the menu choose "mesh" -> "symmetrize"
Then select the correct "Direction" in the Redo panel (the pop-up panel with the settings for the tool)
Make sure your objects origin is in the centre of the object as this is where the symmetrize-ing will be based.

[Blender docs: symmetrize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/symmetrize.html#bpy-ops-mesh-symmetrize)